# Clicked add button but navigate to show page

Tags: react-native, button, react-navigation

I want to add without navigate to show page but when i click an add button, it navigates to show page and after this, it adds. I have a same issue with delete button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZN1r.png)

It should run without go to show page and stay index screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onPress` function in your `FlatList` item title will be triggered when you add items into the state.

You can get rid of this by lambda expression.

```js
export default function IndexScreen({navigation}){
  const { state, addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title={"Add"} onPress={addBlogPost} />
      <FlatList 
        data={state}
        keyExtractor={(blogPosts) => blogPosts.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return(
            <View style={StyleSheet.listStyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {navigation.navigate("Show")}}>  //Change this onPress method
                <Text style={StyleSheet.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{deleteBlogPost(item.id)}}>
                <MaterialIcons name="delete" size={24} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer and help. It works.